# Datatable Not Drawing When Applying External Filters

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

No idea whats going on but i have 3 external filters that i want to use to filter my `Datatable` but i can not get them working at all and can't figure out why or what i'm doing wrong.

**Index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        Filter results
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Use the filters to filter the results.</p>
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="form-group" data-column="2">
                        <label for="companyNameField">Company name</label>
                        <input id="companyNameField" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-group" data-column="1">
                        <label for="typeDropdown">Type</label>
                        <select id="typeDropdown" class="form-control">
                            <option id="typeAll">All</option>
                            <option id="typeChan">Channel</option>
                            <option id="typeCust">Customer</option>
                            <option id="typeResell">Reseller</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-group" data-column="8">
                        <label for="accStatusDropdown">Account status</label>
                        <select id="accStatusDropdown" class="form-control">
                            <option id="accStatAll">All</option>
                            <option id="accStatActive">Active</option>
                            <option id="accStatClosed">Closed</option>
                            <option id="accStatSus">Suspended</option>
                            <option id="accStatFraud">Suspended (Fraud)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <table id="accoutSearchDataTable" class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Contact name</th>
                    <th>Tel no.</th>
                    <th>Mobile no.</th>
                    <th>Email address</th>
                    <th>Prefix</th>
                    <th>Account status</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS File**

```
$('#accoutSearchDataTable').DataTable({
    "ordering": true, // Allows ordering
    "paging": true, // Pagination
    "searching": false, // Searchbox
    "info": false, // Shows 'Showing X of X' information
    "pagingType": 'simple_numbers', // Shows Previous, page numbers & next buttons only
    "pageLength": 10, // Defaults number of rows to display in table. If changing this value change the show/hide below
    "sDom": '<"wrapper"lfptip>',
    "lengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        $('select[name=accoutSearchDataTable_length]').addClass('form-group, form-control');

        // Shows/Hides dropdown and paginator depending on number of results returned
        if (accoutSearchDataTableCount < 10) {
            $('#accoutSearchDataTable_paginate, #accoutSearchDataTable_length').hide();
        } else {
            $('#accoutSearchDataTable_paginate, #accoutSearchDataTable_length').show();
        }

        if (accoutSearchDataTableCount > 1) {
            $('#noResultsWording').hide();
        }

        // Shows/Hides paginator if only one page displayed
        if ($('#accoutSearchDataTable_next').hasClass('disabled') && $('#accoutSearchDataTable_previous').hasClass('disabled')) {
            $('#accoutSearchDataTable_paginate').hide();
        } else {
            $('#accoutSearchDataTable_paginate').show();
        }
    },
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu":
        "<span class='mb-2' style='display: flex'>" +
        "<span class='mr-2 d-flex align-items-center'>Displaying</span>" +
        "_MENU_" +
        "<span class='ml-2 d-flex align-items-center'>records</span>" +
        "</span>"
    },
    'ajax': {
        "type": 'GET',
        "url": 'js/testFiles/accountSearch.json',
        "data": function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        "dataSrc": function (res) {
            accoutSearchDataTableCount = res.data.length;
            return res.data;
        },
        "error": function () {
            $('#accoutSearchDataTable_wrapper').hide();
            $('#existingRuleLoadErrorMessage').html(
                '<p>There was an issue retrieving data. Please try again.</p>' +
                '<p>If the error keeps occurring, please get in touch.</p>').addClass('text-danger');
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "id"
        },
        {
            "data": "type"
        },
        {
            "data": "company"
        },
        {
            "data": "contactname"
        },
        {
            "data": "telno"
        },
        {
            "data": "mobileno"
        },
        {
            "data": "emailaddress"
        },
        {
            "data": "prefix"
        },
        {
            "data": "accountstatus"
        },
        {
            "searchable": false, // Stops search in the fields
            "sorting": false, // Stops sorting
            "orderable": false, // Stops ordering
            "data": null,
            "render": function (data) {
                return '<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center alert alert-info m-0 roundButton">' +
                '<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>' +
                '</div>'
            }
        },
    ],
    "destroy": true
});

$('#typeDropdown').on('change', function () {
    var typeVal = this.value;
    alert(typeVal)

    if (typeVal != '') {
        alert('typeDropdown IF')
        $('#accoutSearchDataTable').DataTable().columns(1).search(typeVal).draw();
    } else {
        alert('typeDropdown ELSE')
    }
});

$('#accStatusDropdown').on('change', function () {
    var statusVal = this.value;
    alert(statusVal)

    if (statusVal != '') {
        alert('accStatusDropdown IF')
        $('#accoutSearchDataTable').DataTable().columns(8).search(statusVal).draw();
    } else {
        alert('accStatusDropdown ELSE')
    }
});

$('#companyNameField').on('keyup', function () {
    var nameVal = this.value;
    alert(nameVal)

    if (nameVal != '') {
        alert('companyNameField IF')
        $('#accoutSearchDataTable').DataTable().columns(3).search(nameVal).draw();
    } else {
        alert('companyNameField ELSE')
    }
});
```

All my alerts are working but the table does not filter.

Filters in the `dropdowns` are:

**Type:** Reseller, Channel, Customer

**Status:** Active, Closed, Susspended

[image]

Comment: 136 lines of JS code (which is unnecessarily verbose, by the way, at least, because you set certain options explicitly to their default values) don't look like *minimal* reproducible sample. However, I'm sure, you'll find your way out as you're the author of the answers to your own questions that are most often accepted ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Instance of Datatable and then try to reload it.

```
var dataTable=$('#accoutSearchDataTable').DataTable({....
```

access for filter

```
$('#typeDropdown').on('change', function() {
    var typeVal = this.value;

    if (typeVal != '') {
        dataTable.column(1).search(typeVal).draw();
    } else {
        alert('typeDropdown ELSE');
    }
});

$('#accStatusDropdown').on('change', function() {
    var statusVal = this.value;

    if (statusVal != '') {
        dataTable.column(8).search(statusVal).draw();
    } else {
        alert('accStatusDropdown ELSE');
    }
});

$('#companyNameField').on('keyup', function() {
    var nameVal = this.value;

    if (nameVal != '') {
        dataTable.column(3).search(nameVal).draw();
    } else {
        alert('companyNameField ELSE');
    }
});
```

and `"searching": true,`

https://jsfiddle.net/12uk68y9/

Comment: Its still not drawing even when i have made your changes.  There's no errors in `console.log` or anything at all

Comment: I have updated the answer try .column instead of .columns.
and "searching": true,

Comment: -Excellent. First i made the changes and it didn't work so i took your code, found the parts you removed, re-added them and for what ever reason it starts working. No idea what was missing nor am i looking as been stuck on this for almost 2 days and lost a lot of hair through it.  Working and leaving it at that. Thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
"searching": false, // Searchbox
```

To this:

```
"searching": true, // Searchbox
```

From the datatable documents:

> Please be aware that technically the search in DataTables is actually a filter, since it is subtractive, removing data from the data set as the input becomes more complex. It is named "search" here, and elsewhere in the DataTables API for consistency and to ensure there are no conflicts with other methods of a similar name (specific the filter() API method).
>   Note that if you wish to use the search abilities of DataTables this must remain true - to remove the default search input box whilst retaining searching abilities (for example you might use the search() method)

Comment: I am not using the built in `Datatable` searchbox hense why its set to `false`. I am using my own fields

Comment: @murday1983 did you try it? turn searching to true!!

Comment: i **DONT** want to use the built in Datatable search box.  But in your case i have tried setting it to `true` and removed the built in Datatable search box from the `DOM`

Comment: You have to set searching true for the filter to work, yes you can remove the search box from the DOM.
and if it helped please accept the answer :)